# Url routing regex help

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I'm trying to create a url routing script for my new CMS but must confess that regex isn't my strong side. So far i keep running into errors or no results.

What i'm trying to accomplish is using certain tags like `:id` `:year` `:slug` etc...

Can anybody help me out or guide me to the right direction with this, that is how to use preg_match or similar functions to find the right "url pattern"? Google has not been doing it job for once :S

**ADDED**

Example url `http://www.mysite.com/post/2011/08/15/title-of-a-blogg-post/`

If i have a route database and one pattern is for example `post/:year/:month/:day/:slug` i want it to match this pattern and call a certain controller, action and in this example a certain article.

The regex array i created looks like

```
$patterns = array(
    ":id"               => "/^[0-9]*$/",
    ":year"             => "/^([0-9]{4})*$/",
    ":year_short"       => "/^([0-9]{2})*$/",
    ":month"            => "/^([0-9]{2})*$/",
    ":day"              => "/^([0-9]{2})*$/",
    ":slug"             => "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$"
);
```

I reckon i need to replace `:id` to `/^[0-9]*$/` and afterwards run a preg_match to find if the url pattern exists in my routes table. However i don't know if i'm using the right regex patterns or just completely lost.

My `.htaccess` file is (because i need to use $_GET as well)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I use this basically to fetch the url and leave out $_GET variables.

```
$route_orginal = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
if(strpos($route_orginal, "?")!=FALSE) {
       list($route_orginal, $get_orginal) = explode("?", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
}

if( substr($route_orginal,(strlen($route_orginal)-1),strlen($route_orginal)) == "/") {
        $this->routes = substr($route_orginal,1,(strlen($route_orginal)-2));
} else {
    $this->routes = substr($route_orginal,1,strlen($route_orginal));
}
```

Comment: The manual explains the regex patterns http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php, and http://regular-expressions.info/ is a useful introduction. Also tools like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world can help crafting them.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question, What is the input, your code and an explanation what is not working and what you exactly expect as result.

Comment: Hope the code i added explains it a little better what i'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Found the solution to my question :D Had to go through many many regex patterns and finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

But if you want a URL like www.mysite.com/tags/id-year-slug

where every tag is seperated by a hyphen, you could do like this:

First, you need a .htaccess file in your root to create pretty urls.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/tags/([A-Za-z-]+)$ index.php?tags=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your index, you explode the tags by the - delimiter:

```
$tags = explode('-',$_GET['tags']);
```

Now you have an array of tags, which you can use for your sql and the url is pretty - high five!

Comment: thx for your answer but it's not what i was looking for exactly. I've updated my question so i hope it can shed some more light on what i'm looking for.

Comment: Found the solution to this question :)